# Can't connect to a database (server) via MS SQL PHP Generator

Tags: php, sql-server

I'm using the software called "MS SQL PHP Generator" which connects to a remote database from my machine.

I specified the correct username, password and server name.

However, I am unable to connect: getting an error saying "Connection not allowed or server doesn't exist".

Is there a configuration I must set up in the MS SQL Server Managment Studio? The software we're using to manage the database.

Here's a pic: http://img860.imageshack.us/img860/3096/so1zc.jpg

Edit: In the SQL managment studio I wen't to permissions, and I saw that my account doesn't have the persmission "Connect SQL". Could this be the issue?

Comment: Make sure SQLServer is configured with Mixed Mode Authentication (default is Windows authentication)

Comment: Do you mean "SQL server and Windows authentication mode"? If so, it is also checked.

Comment: I wen't through the docs - it seems to me that if I wan't to connect to the database, I must login as "sa" user? As currently, I'm not connecting with the system admin user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you do not have to connect as sa - rather, you should NOT. Make sure to grant the account you are connecting with access to the database to are connecting to. For example, create a new database named TEST. Then, create an SQL Server login named test_user. When you create the user, select the User Mapping tab (over on the left of the window) and check the box next to database TEST. Down below, set the account to be in the db_datareader role. Now try connecting via code. There's nothing to query, but you should establish a connection to database TEST.

You also have to make sure that the remote SQL Server: allows remote connections, is not behind a firewall, is not running on a port other than the default 1433, etc, etc.